# Horizontal stacked bar plot and add labels to each section

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I am trying to replicate the following image in matplotlib and it seems `barh` is my only option. Though it appears that you can't stack `barh` graphs so I don't know what to do

[image]

If you know of a better python library to draw this kind of thing, please let me know.

This is all I could come up with as a start:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

people = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
bottomdata = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
topdata = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.barh(y_pos, bottomdata,color='r',align='center')
ax.barh(y_pos, topdata,color='g',align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.set_xlabel('Distance')

plt.show()
```

I would then have to add labels individually using `ax.text` which would be tedious. Ideally I would like to just specify the width of the part to be inserted then it updates the center of that section with a string of my choosing. The labels on the outside (e.g. 3800) I can add myself later, it is mainly the labeling over the bar section itself and creating this stacked method in a nice way I'm having problems with. Can you even specify a 'distance' i.e. span of color in any way?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Edit 2: for more heterogeneous data. (I've left the above method since I find it more usual to work with the same number of records per series)

Answering the two parts of the question:

a) `barh` returns a container of handles to all the patches that it drew. You can use the coordinates of the patches to aid the text positions.

b) Following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654415/1643946) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654564/1643946) answers to the question that I noted before (see [Horizontal stacked bar chart in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16653815/1643946)), you can stack bar graphs horizontally by setting the 'left' input.

and additionally c) handling data that is less uniform in shape.

Below is one way you could handle data that is less uniform in shape is simply to process each segment independently.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some labels for each row
people = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')
r = len(people)

# how many data points overall (average of 3 per person)
n = r * 3

# which person does each segment belong to?
rows = np.random.randint(0, r, (n,))
# how wide is the segment?
widths = np.random.randint(3,12, n,)
# what label to put on the segment (xrange in py2.7, range for py3)
labels = range(n)
colors ='rgbwmc'

patch_handles = []

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)



left = np.zeros(r,)
row_counts = np.zeros(r,)

for (r, w, l) in zip(rows, widths, labels):
    print r, w, l
    patch_handles.append(ax.barh(r, w, align='center', left=left[r],
        color=colors[int(row_counts[r]) % len(colors)]))
    left[r] += w
    row_counts[r] += 1
    # we know there is only one patch but could enumerate if expanded
    patch = patch_handles[-1][0] 
    bl = patch.get_xy()
    x = 0.5*patch.get_width() + bl[0]
    y = 0.5*patch.get_height() + bl[1]
    ax.text(x, y, "%d%%" % (l), ha='center',va='center')
  
y_pos = np.arange(8)
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.set_xlabel('Distance')

plt.show()
```

Which produces a graph like this [image: heterogeneous hbars], with a different number of segments present in each series.

Note that this is not particularly efficient since each segment used an individual call to `ax.barh`.  There may be more efficient methods (e.g. by padding a matrix with zero-width segments or nan values) but this likely to be problem-specific and is a distinct question.

---

Edit: updated to answer both parts of the question.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

people = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')
segments = 4

# generate some multi-dimensional data & arbitrary labels
data = 3 + 10* np.random.rand(segments, len(people))
percentages = (np.random.randint(5,20, (len(people), segments)))
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

colors ='rgbwmc'
patch_handles = []
left = np.zeros(len(people)) # left alignment of data starts at zero
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    patch_handles.append(ax.barh(y_pos, d, 
      color=colors[i%len(colors)], align='center', 
      left=left))
    # accumulate the left-hand offsets
    left += d
    
# go through all of the bar segments and annotate
for j in range(len(patch_handles)):
    for i, patch in enumerate(patch_handles[j].get_children()):
        bl = patch.get_xy()
        x = 0.5*patch.get_width() + bl[0]
        y = 0.5*patch.get_height() + bl[1]
        ax.text(x,y, "%d%%" % (percentages[i,j]), ha='center')

ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.set_xlabel('Distance')

plt.show()
```

You can achieve a result along these lines (note: the percentages I used have nothing to do with the bar widths, as the relationship in the example seems unclear):

[image: example output]

See [Horizontal stacked bar chart in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16653815/1643946) for some ideas on stacking horizontal bar plots.

---

Answer (score 18):

### Imports and Test DataFrame

- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**
- For vertical stacked bars see [Stacked Bar Chart with Centered Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895640/7758804)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create sample data as shown in the OP
np.random.seed(365)
people = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')
bottomdata = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
topdata = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Female': bottomdata, 'Male': topdata}, index=people)

# display(df)
   Female   Male
A   12.41   7.42
B    9.42   4.10
C    9.85   7.38
D    8.89  10.53
E    8.44   5.92
F    6.68  11.86
G   10.67  12.97
H    6.05   7.87
```

### Updated with `matplotlib v3.4.2`

- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)
- See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples with `.bar_label`.
- `labels = [f'{v.get_width():.2f}%' if v.get_width() > 0 else '' for v in c ]` for python < 3.8, without the assignment expression (`:=`).

#### Plotted using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `kind='barh'`

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(8, 6))

for c in ax.containers:
    
    # customize the label to account for cases when there might not be a bar section
    labels = [f'{w:.2f}%' if (w := v.get_width()) > 0 else '' for v in c ]
    
    # set the bar label
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center')

    # uncomment and use the next line if there are no nan or 0 length sections; just use fmt to add a % (the previous two lines of code are not needed, in this case)
#     ax.bar_label(c, fmt='%.2f%%', label_type='center')

# move the legend
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.025, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)

# add labels
ax.set_ylabel("People", fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel("Percent", fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Using seaborn

- [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) does not have an option for stacked bar plots, however, [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) and [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) can be used to create horizontal stacked bars.
- seaborn typically requires the dataframe to be in a long, instead of wide, format, so use [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to reshape the dataframe.

#### Reshape dataframe

```py
# convert the dataframe to a long form
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'index': 'People'})
dfm = df.melt(id_vars='People', var_name='Gender', value_name='Percent')

# display(dfm)
   People  Gender    Percent
0       A  Female  12.414557
1       B  Female   9.416027
2       C  Female   9.846105
3       D  Female   8.885621
4       E  Female   8.438872
5       F  Female   6.680709
6       G  Female  10.666258
7       H  Female   6.050124
8       A    Male   7.420860
9       B    Male   4.104433
10      C    Male   7.383738
11      D    Male  10.526158
12      E    Male   5.916262
13      F    Male  11.857227
14      G    Male  12.966913
15      H    Male   7.865684
```

#### `sns.histplot`: axes-level plot

```py
fig, axe = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.histplot(data=dfm, y='People', hue='Gender', discrete=True, weights='Percent', multiple='stack', ax=axe)

# iterate through each set of containers
for c in axe.containers:
    # add bar annotations
    axe.bar_label(c, fmt='%.2f%%', label_type='center')

axe.set_xlabel('Percent')
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### `sns.displot`: figure-level plot

```py
g = sns.displot(data=dfm, y='People', hue='Gender', discrete=True, weights='Percent', multiple='stack', height=6)

# iterate through each facet / supbplot
for axe in g.axes.flat:
    # iteate through each set of containers
    for c in axe.containers:
        # add the bar annotations
        axe.bar_label(c, fmt='%.2f%%', label_type='center')
    axe.set_xlabel('Percent')

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Original Answer - before `matplotlib v3.4.2`

- The easiest way to plot a horizontal or vertical stacked bar, is to load the data into a `pandas.DataFrame`

  - This will plot, and annotate correctly, even when all categories (`'People'`), don't have all segments (e.g. some value is 0 or `NaN`)
- Once the data is in the dataframe:

  1. It's easier to manipulate and analyze
  2. It can be plotted with the `matplotlib` engine, using:

     - [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html)

       - `label_text = f'{width}'` for annotations
     - [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

       - `label_text = f'{height}'` for annotations
       - [SO: Vertical Stacked Bar Chart with Centered Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895640/7758804)
- These methods return a `matplotlib.axes.Axes` or a `numpy.ndarray` of them.
- Using the `.patches` method unpacks a list of [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9fcu.png) objects, one for each of the sections of the stacked bar.

  - Each `.Rectangle` has methods for extracting the various values that define the rectangle.
  - Each `.Rectangle` is in order from left the right, and bottom to top, so all the `.Rectangle` objects, for each level, appear in order, when iterating through `.patches`.
- The labels are made using an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), `label_text = f'{width:.2f}%'`, so any additional text can be added as needed.

### Plot and Annotate

- Plotting the bar, is 1 line, the remainder is annotating the rectangles

```
# plot the dataframe with 1 line
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(8, 6))

# .patches is everything inside of the chart
for rect in ax.patches:
    # Find where everything is located
    height = rect.get_height()
    width = rect.get_width()
    x = rect.get_x()
    y = rect.get_y()
    
    # The height of the bar is the data value and can be used as the label
    label_text = f'{width:.2f}%'  # f'{width:.2f}' to format decimal values
    
    # ax.text(x, y, text)
    label_x = x + width / 2
    label_y = y + height / 2
    
    # only plot labels greater than given width
    if width > 0:
        ax.text(label_x, label_y, label_text, ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8)

# move the legend
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)

# add labels
ax.set_ylabel("People", fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel("Percent", fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Example with Missing Segment

```py
# set one of the dataframe values to 0
df.iloc[4, 1] = 0
```

- Note the annotations are all in the correct location from `df`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For this case, the above answers work perfectly. The issue I had, and didn't find a plug-and-play solution online, was that I often have to plot stacked bars in multi-subplot figures, with many values, which tend to have very non-homogenous amplitudes.

(Note: I work usually with pandas dataframes, and matplotlib. I couldn't make the bar_label() method of matplotlib to work all the times.)

So, I just give a kind of ad-hoc, but easily generalizable solution. In this example, I was working with single-row dataframes (for power-exchange monitoring purposes per hour), so, my dataframe (df) had just one row.

(I provide an example figure to show how this can be useful in very densely-packed plots)

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9akd8.png

'''
This implementation produces a stacked, horizontal bar plot.

df --> pandas dataframe. Columns are used as the iterator, and only the firs value of each column is used.

waterfall--> bool: if True, apart from the stack-direction, also a perpendicular offset is added.

cyclic_offset_x --> list (of any length) or None: loop through these values to use as x-offset pixels.

cyclic_offset_y --> list (of any length) or None: loop through these values to use as y-offset pixels.

ax --> matplotlib Axes, or None: if None, creates a new axis and figure.
'''

```
    def magic_stacked_bar(df, waterfall=False, cyclic_offset_x=None, cyclic_offset_y=None, ax=None):



        if isinstance(cyclic_offset_x, type(None)):
            cyclic_offset_x = [0, 0]
        if isinstance(cyclic_offset_y, type(None)):
            cyclic_offset_y = [0, 0]

        ax0 = ax
        if isinstance(ax, type(None)):
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            fig.set_size_inches(19, 10)

        cycler = 0;
        prev = 0 # summation variable to make it stacked
        for c in df.columns:
            if waterfall:
                y = c ; label = "" # bidirectional stack
            else:
                y = 0; label = c # unidirectional stack
            ax.barh(y=y, width=df[c].values[0], height=1, left=prev, label = label)
            prev += df[c].values[0] # add to sum-stack

            offset_x = cyclic_offset_x[divmod(cycler, len(cyclic_offset_x))[1]]
            offset_y = cyclic_offset_y[divmod(cycler, len(cyclic_offset_y))[1]]

            ax.annotate(text="{}".format(int(df[c].values[0])), xy=(prev - df[c].values / 2, y),
                        xytext=(offset_x, offset_y), textcoords='offset pixels',
                        ha='center', va='top', fontsize=8,
                        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.01, width=0.3, headwidth=0.3),
                        bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='grey', alpha=0.5))

            cycler += 1

        if not waterfall:
            ax.legend() # if waterfall, the index annotates the columns. If 
                        # waterfall ==False, the legend annotates the columns
        if isinstance(ax0, type(None)):
            ax.set_title("Voi la")
            ax.set_xlabel("UltraWatts")
            plt.show()
        else:
            return ax
```

''' (Sometimes, it is more tedious and requires some custom functions to make the labels look alright.

'''

```
A, B = 80,80
n_units = df.shape[1]
cyclic_offset_x = -A*np.cos(2*np.pi / (2*n_units)  *np.arange(n_units))
cyclic_offset_y = B*np.sin(2*np.pi / (2*n_units) * np.arange(n_units)) + B/2
```

Comment: Can you please format your answer? It's not that friendly to read at the moment