# Stacked Bar Chart with Centered Labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, stacked-bar-chart

I'm trying to "robustly" center the data labels in a stacked bar chart. A simple code example and the result are given below. As you can see, the data labels aren't really centered in all rectangles. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = [45, 17, 47]
B = [91, 70, 72]

fig = plt.figure(facecolor="white")

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
bar_width = 0.5
bar_l = np.arange(1, 4)
tick_pos = [i + (bar_width / 2) for i in bar_l]

ax1 = ax.bar(bar_l, A, width=bar_width, label="A", color="green")
ax2 = ax.bar(bar_l, B, bottom=A, width=bar_width, label="B", color="blue")
ax.set_ylabel("Count", fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel("Class", fontsize=18)
ax.legend(loc="best")
plt.xticks(tick_pos, ["C1", "C2", "C3"], fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)

for r1, r2 in zip(ax1, ax2):
    h1 = r1.get_height()
    h2 = r2.get_height()
    plt.text(r1.get_x() + r1.get_width() / 2., h1 / 2., "%d" % h1, ha="center", va="bottom", color="white", fontsize=16, fontweight="bold")
    plt.text(r2.get_x() + r2.get_width() / 2., h1 + h2 / 2., "%d" % h2, ha="center", va="bottom", color="white", fontsize=16, fontweight="bold")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why you wrote `va="bottom"`? You have to use `va="center"`.
[image]

Answer (score 60):

- The following method is more succinct, and easily scales.
- Putting the data into a `pandas.DataFrame` is the easiest way to plot a stacked bar plot.
- Using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar(stacked=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html), or [`pandas.DataFrame.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), is the easiest way to plot a stacked bar plot.

  - This method returns a `matplotlib.axes.Axes` or a `numpy.ndarray` of them.
- Since `seaborn` is just a high-level API for `matplotlib`, these solutions also work with `seaborn` plots, as shown in [How to annotate a seaborn barplot with the aggregated value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64797097/7758804).
- For horizontal stacked bars, see [Horizontal stacked bar plot and add labels to each section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64202669/7758804)
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

## Imports & Test DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = [45, 17, 47]
B = [91, 70, 72]
C = [68, 43, 13]

# pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}, index=['C1', 'C2', 'C3'])

     A   B   C
C1  45  91  68
C2  17  70  43
C3  47  72  13
```

## Updated for `matplotlib v3.4.2`

- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html), which will automatically center the values in the bar.
- See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples with `.bar_label`.
- Tested with `pandas v1.2.4`, which is using `matplotlib` as the plot engine.
- If some sections of the bar plot will be zero, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64202669/7758804), which shows how to customize the `labels` for `.bar_label()`.
- `ax.bar_label(c, fmt='%0.0f', label_type='center')` will change the number format to show no decimal places, if needed.

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(8, 6), rot=0, xlabel='Class', ylabel='Count')
for c in ax.containers:

    # Optional: if the segment is small or 0, customize the labels
    labels = [v.get_height() if v.get_height() > 0 else '' for v in c]
    
    # remove the labels parameter if it's not needed for customized labels
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center')
```

[image]

#### Other options for removing labels for small segments can use `fmt`

- With the [matplotlib 3.7 Update](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.7.0.html#additional-format-string-options-in-bar-label), the `fmt` argument of `bar_label` now accepts {}-style format strings.
- `fmt=lambda x: f'{x:.0f}' if x > 0 else ''`
- `fmt=lambda x: np.where(x > 0, f'{x:.0f}', '')` with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(8, 6), rot=0, xlabel='Class', ylabel='Count')
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, fmt=lambda x: f'{x:.0f}' if x > 0 else '', label_type='center')
```

### Seaborn Options

- `seaborn` is a high-level api for `matplotlib`
- The [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) api doesn't have an option for stacking, but it "can" be implemented with [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html), or [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html).

#### Seaborn DataFrame Format

```py
# create the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'cat': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']})

    A   B   C cat
0  45  91  68  C1
1  17  70  43  C2
2  47  72  13  C3

# convert the dataframe to a long form
df = df.melt(id_vars='cat')

  cat variable  value
0  C1        A     45
1  C2        A     17
2  C3        A     47
3  C1        B     91
4  C2        B     70
5  C3        B     72
6  C1        C     68
7  C2        C     43
8  C3        C     13
```

#### axes-level plot

```py
# plot
ax = sns.histplot(data=df, x='cat', hue='variable', weights='value', discrete=True, multiple='stack')

# iterate through each container
for c in ax.containers:

    # Optional: if the segment is small or 0, customize the labels
    labels = [v.get_height() if v.get_height() > 0 else '' for v in c]
    
    # remove the labels parameter if it's not needed for customized labels
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center')
```

[image]

#### figure-level plot

```py
# plot
g = sns.displot(data=df, x='cat', hue='variable', weights='value', discrete=True, multiple='stack')

# iterate through each axes
for ax in g.axes.flat:

    # iterate through each container
    for c in ax.containers:

        # Optional: if the segment is small or 0, customize the labels
        labels = [v.get_height() if v.get_height() > 0 else '' for v in c]

        # remove the labels parameter if it's not needed for customized labels
        ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center')
```

[image]

---

## Original Answer

- Using the `.patches` method unpacks a list of [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html?highlight=rectangle#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) objects, one for each of the sections of the stacked bar.

  - Each `.Rectangle` has methods for extracting the various values that define the rectangle.
  - Each `.Rectangle` is in order from left to right, and bottom to top, so all the `.Rectangle` objects, for each level, appear in order, when iterating through `.patches`.
- The labels are made using an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), `label_text = f'{height}'`, so any additional text can be added as needed, such as `label_text = f'{height}%'`

  - `label_text = f'{height:0.0f}'` will display numbers with no decimal places.

### Plot

```py
plt.style.use('ggplot')

ax = df.plot(stacked=True, kind='bar', figsize=(12, 8), rot='horizontal')

# .patches is everything inside of the chart
for rect in ax.patches:
    # Find where everything is located
    height = rect.get_height()
    width = rect.get_width()
    x = rect.get_x()
    y = rect.get_y()
    
    # The height of the bar is the data value and can be used as the label
    label_text = f'{height}'  # f'{height:.2f}' to format decimal values
    
    # ax.text(x, y, text)
    label_x = x + width / 2
    label_y = y + height / 2

    # plot only when height is greater than specified value
    if height > 0:
        ax.text(label_x, label_y, label_text, ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8)
    
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)    
ax.set_ylabel("Count", fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel("Class", fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

[image]

- To plot a horizontal bar:

  - `kind='barh'`
  - `label_text = f'{width}'`
  - `if width > 0:`
- Attribution: [jsoma/chart.py](https://gist.github.com/jsoma/c61e56819e4ae315ad5d194a630ccb23)