# trying to sort data set by two columns so the plot will be shown in decreasing order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am working with this data set.

| Month | Region | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| April | Bronx | 15 |
| April | Brooklyn | 14 |
| April | Manhattan | 8 |
| April | Nassau County | 2 |
| April | Orange County | 1 |
| April | Out of State | 3 |
| April | Queens | 17 |
| April | Staten Island | 3 |
| April | Unknown | 1 |
| April | Westchester County | 2 |
| July | Bronx | 54 |
| July | Brooklyn | 4 |
| July | Central Valley, NY | 1 |
| July | Clifton, NJ | 1 |
| July | Hackensack, NJ | 1 |
| July | Manhattan | 11 |
| July | Mount Vernon, NY | 1 |
| July | Port Washington, NY | 1 |
| July | Queens | 9 |
| July | Rahway. NJ | 1 |
| July | Staten Island | 1 |
| July | Wappingers Fall, NY | 1 |
| July | Yonker, NY | 3 |
| June | Bronx | 2 |
| June | Brooklyn | 31 |
| June | New Jersey | 2 |
| June | Orange County | 1 |
| June | Queens | 5 |
| March | Bronx | 5 |
| March | Brooklyn | 8 |
| March | Manhattan | 1 |
| March | Nassau County | 4 |
| March | Out of State | 2 |
| March | Queens | 36 |
| March | Suffolk County | 1 |
| March | Unknown | 4 |
| March | Westchester County | 1 |
| May | Bronx | 2 |
| May | Brooklyn | 7 |
| May | Manhattan | 1 |
| May | Nassau County | 2 |
| May | Out of State | 1 |
| May | Queens | 6 |
| May | Staten Island | 17 |
| May | Unknown | 3 |
| May | Westchester County | 1 |

The plot I am getting is sorting by alphabetical order where I want it to sort by the highest count per region including all of the months.

```
#chart 1 - attendence by region

#making the dataframe shown above
s=df.groupby(['Month','Borough']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
#s=s.sort_values(['Count'], ascending=False).reset_index()
df1=pd.DataFrame(s)

#plotting graph
sns.set(font_scale = 1.5)
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'font.family':'Century Gothic', 'font.serif':['Century Gothic']})
ax = df1.pivot_table(index='Borough',
                    columns='Month',
                    values='Count',
                    aggfunc='sum',
                    sort=False).plot(kind='barh',grid=False, stacked=True, figsize=(15,10), width=0.9)

#bar labels
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, fmt=lambda x: int(x) if x>0 else '', label_type='center')
plt.xlabel('Count')
plt.ylabel('Regions')
plt.title('<b>Attendence By Region</b>')
plt.legend(title='Months',loc='upper right')
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
```

[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGiWj.png)

I cant seem to figure out how to have the bar chart ordered by length. I tried ordering the dataframe that the chart is being made from but it didnt work. If you could help me, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360294/sort-stacked-bar-chart-individually-in-matplotlib

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309507/stacked-bar-plot-using-matplotlib/55318932#55318932

Answer (score 1):

Sort your `pivot` by the sum of the values:

```
pvt = df1.pivot_table(index='Region',
                      columns='Month',
                      values='Count',
                      aggfunc='sum',
                      sort=False)

order = pvt.sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index

pvt.loc[order].plot(kind='barh', grid=False, stacked=True, figsize=(15,10), width=0.9)
```

Note that you can also replace the `pivot` with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pvt = pd.crosstab(df['Region'], df['Month'])
order = pvt.sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index
pvt.loc[order].plot(kind='barh', grid=False, stacked=True, figsize=(15,10), width=0.9)
```

[image]