# How to plot dataframe as a stacked bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to plot a dataframe as stacked bar chart. However I fail to show each subset of the bar. It's only shown as one bar.
Don't really know how to progress, because when I try each solution I find online it works with the dataset provided by the example but not with mine. Hence I believe that I need to change my dataframe, but I fail to see how.

Update. Forgot to poste the code and than forgot the question.
So update:
I run this code:

```
ax1 = dfny.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.legend(title='labels', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

The dataframe looks as this:
[Dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw94A.png)

The result looks like this:
[Link to result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEDxi.png)

However I was expecting all the columns number from
1416-1415-1417-1420-1426 in a stacked bar chart, like:
[Link to stackovflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309507/stacked-bar-plot-using-matplotlib)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, could you please post the code of your attempt?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated the question with code now.