# How to change sort order of stacked bar chart using seaborn objects (v0.12)

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am using seaborn objects to plot a stacked bar chart and I am wondering what the right was is to change the sort order in which the bars are stacked.

Looking at this example:

```
import seaborn.objects as so
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
so.Plot(
    penguins,
    x="species",
    y="body_mass_g",
    color="sex",
).add(so.Bar(width=0.2), so.Agg(), so.Stack())
```

[image]
the order is `['male', 'female']`. How do I reverse that order?

The only answer I came up with is to sort the input data. It appears that the order of the bars depends on the order of appearance in the dataset.

```
so.Plot(
    penguins.sort_values(by="sex", ascending=True),
    x="species",
    y="body_mass_g",
    color="sex",
).add(so.Bar(width=0.2), so.Agg(), so.Stack()).scale(
    color=so.Nominal(order=["Male", "Female"])
)
```

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this without changing the input data?

Comment: There's a question on this topic for matplotlib, however [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68744777) uses `sns.barplot` and may be adaptable to your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the order for the `color` variable with a scale:

```
(
    so.Plot(penguins, x="species", y="body_mass_g", color="sex")
    .add(so.Bar(width=0.2), so.Agg(), so.Stack())
    .scale(color=so.Nominal(order=["Female", "Male"]))  # <--- Add this line
)
```

[image]

It looks like the stack operation is still putting the female bars on top of the male bars, which is interesting and may be a bug, but also may be what you're looking for here (i.e. that the stack order matches the legend order from top-to-bottom). There is an issue to make that happen by default: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2888

Comment: Hi @mwaskomm, the order of the legend was just sugar on top, I was more looking for a way to get the bars in a defined order, independent of how the data was sorted.