# How to make this type of horizontal barplot in python/seaborn?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, bar-chart

I was wondering if its possible to make a bar plot that looks like this in Python:

[image]

Specifically, the details I'm interested in are:

- Have the grey bars for each category take up the entire width of plot
- Have the percent value take up that percentage of the grey bar in a different color
- Have the category name be inside the bars rather than outside
- Show the percentage values next to the colored portion

Comment: Not sure about Seaborn but there are various ways to do this in matplotlib.  See answers to this question: [stacked bar plot using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44309507/1609514).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first create a bar plot with all values 100 and plot the intended bars on top.

Matplotlib's new `bar_label()` function lets you label the bars with their values.  `ax.text()` can add the y tick labels as text into the plot.

The following code gets some test data from wikipedia (to make things reproducible, the data is hard-coded, as wikipedia can change some details any day).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

'''
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_causes_of_death_by_rate', match='Cause', header=0)[0][['Cause', 'Percent of all deaths']][:-1]
df['Percent of all deaths'] = df['Percent of all deaths'].astype(float)
df = df.sort_values(by='Percent of all deaths', ascending=False)
df.to_dict(orient='list')
'''
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cause': ['Cardiovascular diseases', 'Neoplasms', 'Chronic respiratory diseases', 'Respiratory infections and tuberculosis', 'Neurological disorders', 'Diabetes and kidney diseases', 'Digestive diseases', 'Maternal and neonatal disorders', 'Enteric infections', 'Unintentional injuries', 'Self harm and violence', 'Transport injuries', 'Other non-communicable', 'Sexually transmitted infections', 'Other infectious diseases', 'Tropical diseases and malaria', 'Substance abuse', 'Nutritional deficiencies', 'Musculoskeletal disorders', 'Skin diseases'], 'Percent of all deaths': [31.59, 16.43, 6.97, 6.85, 5.84, 4.55, 4.11, 4.0, 3.31, 3.23, 2.32, 2.3, 2.22, 1.88, 1.57, 1.37, 0.58, 0.52, 0.22, 0.18]})
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, y='Cause', x=[100] * len(df), color='lightgrey', saturation=1)
sns.barplot(data=df, y='Cause', x='Percent of all deaths', color='tomato', saturation=1, ax=ax)

for lbl in ax.get_yticklabels():
     # add the y tick labels as right aligned text into the plot
     ax.text(0.985, lbl.get_position()[1], lbl.get_text(), transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(), ha='right', va='center')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[1], fmt=' %.2f %%') # label the bars
ax.set_xticks([]) # remove the x ticks
ax.set_yticks([]) # remove the y ticks
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.xaxis.label.set_size(20)
ax.set_ylabel('') # remove the y label
ax.margins(x=0) # remove the spacing at the right
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True) # remove the spines
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot with text inside]