# Show values in stacked bar chart pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
   production  consumption
year        
2013    0.426669    0.573331
2014    0.436364    0.563636
2015    0.419941    0.580059
2016    0.448378    0.551622
2017    0.442212    0.557788
2018    0.422724    0.577276
2019    0.445296    0.554704
```

and I plot a stacked bar chart using **df.plot.bar(stacked=True)** function

[image: graph]

Productions and consumptions are in %

Is it possible to add percentages into bars?

Comment: yes, but that would be something for you to try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacked Bar Chart with Centered Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296313/stacked-bar-chart-with-centered-labels)

Comment: Specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895640/15497888) answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's harder than it should be but it's doable:

```py
ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
labels = [f'{i:.0%}' for i in df.to_numpy().flatten(order='F')]

for i, patch in enumerate(ax.patches):
    x, y = patch.get_xy()
    x += patch.get_width() / 2
    y += patch.get_height() / 2
    ax.annotate(labels[i], (x, y), ha='center', va='center', c='white')
```

Result:

[image]