# Plot quantiles on the same bar with labels

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, bar-chart

Is there a way to plot the following bar into a grouped barplot that I could represent it as a single bar where it would be separated, more like overlapping. [image]

What I thought about is using a stacked bar but the problem is I do not want the values to be summed up like here [Stacked Bar Chart with Centered Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296313/stacked-bar-chart-with-centered-labels)

My data looks something like this:

```
    customer avg_price  avg_price2  p_50    p_75    p_90    count
0   A   2.84    5.7681  2.72    3.42    4.090   526181
1   B   2.73    6.3373  2.57    3.52    4.360   646022
2   C   2.51    21.4732 1.67    3.35    5.442   1140
3   D   2.19    9.3906  1.87    3.15    3.430   110729
4   E   2.19    5.6669  2.00    2.70    3.630   703413
```

I want to plot p_50, p_75, p_90 as columns.

So I tried to plot them by overlapping each bar starting with the largest to the lowest. The thing is these being percentiles I can't simply stacked them since they don't necessarily add to a total value.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,11))
df.sort_values(by='avg_price').plot.barh(x='customer', y=['p_90'], width=0.75, ax=ax, color='darkblue');
df.sort_values(by='avg_price').plot.barh(x='customer', y=['p_75'], width=0.75, ax=ax);
df.sort_values(by='avg_price').plot.barh(x='customer', y=['p_50'], width=0.75, ax=ax, color='lightblue');

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=[f'{p:.2f}' for p in df.sort_values(by='avg_price')['p_90']], label_type='center');
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=[f'{p:.2f}' for p in df.sort_values(by='avg_price')['p_75']], label_type='center');
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=[f'{p:.2f}' for p in df.sort_values(by='avg_price')['p_50']], label_type='center');
```

While trying to label each column with their proper the values they overlap.
How can I properly label each section?

[image]

Comment: The plots are not drawn correctly. The bars are stacked on top of each other in the z order. This is an incorrect representation for stacked bars.

Comment: _**What I thought about is using a stacked bar but the problem is I do not want the values to be summed up**_ Your desired way is not the correct way to present stacked bars.

Comment: [Code and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqqJQ.png) & [Code and Plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADcoU.png)