# How to make a multi-level chart column label

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I stopped at this point:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
               'users': [40, 2, 51],
               'buyers': [15, 1, 29],
               'percentage': [37.5000, 50.0000, 56.8627]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# Plot the all users
sns.barplot(x='id', y='users', data=df, palette='Blues', edgecolor='grey', alpha=0.7)
# Plot the buyers
sns.barplot(x='id', y='buyers', data=df, palette='Blues', edgecolor='black', hatch='//')

# display column values
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, fontsize=13)
plt.show()
```

The chart looks like this:

[image]

I also need to include data from the "percentage" frame in the shaded portion of the chart. Please tell me how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add the `'percentage'` values by passing a custom list to the `labels=` parameter in `.bar_label`

  - Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to index the values from `df`.
  - `f"{v.get_height()}: {df.loc[i, 'percentage']}%"` is used to customize the annotation string.
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples using `.bar_label`.
- See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895640/7758804) for additional details about seaborn stacked bars with annotations.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`, `matplotlib 3.5.2`, `seaborn 0.12.0`**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
               'users': [40, 2, 51],
               'buyers': [15, 1, 29],
               'percentage': [37.5000, 50.0000, 56.8627]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# Plot the all users
sns.barplot(x='id', y='users', data=df, palette='Blues', edgecolor='grey', alpha=0.7, ax=ax)
# Plot the buyers
sns.barplot(x='id', y='buyers', data=df, palette='Blues', edgecolor='darkgrey', hatch='//', ax=ax)

# extract the separate containers
c1, c2 = ax.containers

# annotate with the users values
ax.bar_label(c1, fontsize=13)

# annotate with the buyer and percentage values
l2 = [f"{v.get_height()}: {df.loc[i, 'percentage']}%" for i, v in enumerate(c2)]
ax.bar_label(c2, labels=l2, fontsize=8, label_type='center', fontweight='bold')
   
plt.show()
```

[image]