# How to make a multi-level chart column label by hue

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, plot-annotations

This is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73734372/how-to-make-a-multi-level-chart-column-label) question. But now I have a bar-chart with hue.

Here's what I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': ['20-30', '20-30', '20-30', '30-40', '30-40', '30-40', '40-50', '40-50', '40-50', '50-60', '50-60', '50-60'],
               'expenses':['50$', '100$', '200$', '50$', '100$', '200$', '50$', '100$', '200$', '50$', '100$', '200$'],
               'users': [59, 42, 57, 68, 47, 98, 75, 73, 54, 81, 52, 43],
               'buyers': [22, 35, 18, 27, 12, 57, 19, 29, 31, 47, 10, 5],
               'percentage': [37.2881, 83.3333, 31.5789, 39.7058, 25.5319, 58.1632, 25.3333, 39.7260, 57.4074, 58.0246, 19.2307, 11.6279]})
```

| index | age | expenses | users | buyers | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20-30 | 50$ | 59 | 22 | 37.2881 |
| 1 | 20-30 | 100$ | 42 | 35 | 83.3333 |
| 2 | 20-30 | 200$ | 57 | 18 | 31.5789 |
| 3 | 30-40 | 50$ | 68 | 27 | 39.7058 |
| 4 | 30-40 | 100$ | 47 | 12 | 25.5319 |
| 5 | 30-40 | 200$ | 98 | 57 | 58.1632 |
| 6 | 40-50 | 50$ | 75 | 19 | 25.3333 |
| 7 | 40-50 | 100$ | 73 | 29 | 39.726 |
| 8 | 40-50 | 200$ | 54 | 31 | 57.4074 |
| 9 | 50-60 | 50$ | 81 | 47 | 58.0246 |
| 10 | 50-60 | 100$ | 52 | 10 | 19.2307 |
| 11 | 50-60 | 200$ | 43 | 5 | 11.6279 |

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

# Plot the all users
sns.barplot(x='age', y='users', data=df, hue='expenses', palette='Blues', edgecolor='grey', alpha=0.7, ax=ax)
# Plot the buyers
sns.barplot(x='age', y='buyers', data=df, hue='expenses', palette='Blues', edgecolor='darkgrey', hatch='//', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I need to get the [same chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73734372/how-to-make-a-multi-level-chart-column-label). In the case of hue, the code:

```
# extract the separate containers
c1, c2 = ax.containers

# annotate with the users values
ax.bar_label(c1, fontsize=13)

# annotate with the buyer and percentage values
l2 = [f"{v.get_height()}: {df.loc[i, 'percentage']}%" for i, v in enumerate(c2)]
ax.bar_label(c2, labels=l2, fontsize=8, label_type='center', fontweight='bold')
```

no longer works.
I would be glad for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Each object in `ax.containers` represents the bars for a single hue group.

  - When using `bar_label`, the annotations for each bar in `'50$'`, then `'100$'`, and then `'200$'` are added.
- I think it's easier to select the correct data by annotating the `'buyers'` group separately.

  - The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73735105/7758804) to your previous question selects the data from the entire dataframe, but here Boolean indexing is used to select only a segment of the dataframe. Using `print(data)` in each loop will help with understanding.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

# plot the all users
sns.barplot(x='age', y='users', data=df, hue='expenses', palette='Blues', edgecolor='grey', alpha=0.7, ax=ax)

# annotate the bars in the 3 containers (1 container per hue group)
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c)
    
# plot the 'buyers', which adds 3 more containers to ax
sns.barplot(x='age', y='buyers', data=df, hue='expenses', palette='Blues', edgecolor='darkgrey', hatch='//', ax=ax)

# iterate through the last 3 new containers containing the hatched groups 
for c in ax.containers[3:]:
    
    # get the hue label, which will be used to select the data group
    hue_label = c.get_label()
    # select the data based on hue_label
    data = df.loc[df.expenses.eq(hue_label), ['buyers', 'percentage']]
    # customize the labels
    labels = [f"{v.get_height()}: {data.iloc[i, 1]:0.2f}%" for i, v in enumerate(c)]
    # add the labels
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]