# Use Matplotlib to plot 100% Stacked bar from Excel data

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

I can plot a 100% stacked bar from Excel. is it possible to achieve the same with matplotlib ?

[image]

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
        [0.4 , 0.3 , 0.2 , 0.1],
        [0.5 , 0.3 , 0.6 , 0.1],
        [0.1 , 0.4 , 0.2 , 0.8],
        
]

columns = ["A","B","C","D" ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data , columns=columns , index = ["Empty" , "Wrong" , "Correct"] )

df.plot(kind="barh" , stacked=True )

plt.ylabel("Percentages")

plt.show()

print (df)
```

Comment: Try this: `df.T.plot(kind="barh", stacked=True)`

Comment: Thanks! is there a simple way to add the percentages in each bar ?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296313/stacked-bar-chart-with-centered-labels) has what you are looking for.