# How to create a 100% stacked bar plot from a categorical dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I have a dataframe structured like this:

| User | Food 1 | Food 2 | Food 3 | Food 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Steph | Onions | Tomatoes | Cabbages | Potatoes |
| Tom | Potatoes | Tomatoes | Potatoes | Potatoes |
| Fred | Carrots | Cabbages |  | Eggplant |
| Phil | Onions | Eggplant | Eggplant |  |

I want to use the distinct values from across the food columns as categories. I then want to create a Seaborn plot so the % of each category for each column is plotted as a 100% horizontal stacked bar.

My attempt to do this:

```
data = {
    'User' : ['Steph', 'Tom', 'Fred', 'Phil'],
    'Food 1' : ["Onions", "Potatoes", "Carrots", "Onions"],
    'Food 2' : ['Tomatoes', 'Tomatoes', 'Cabbages', 'Eggplant'],
    'Food 3' : ["Cabbages", "Potatoes", "", "Eggplant"],
    'Food 4' : ['Potatoes', 'Potatoes', 'Eggplant', ''],    
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x_ax = ["Onions", "Potatoes", "Carrots", "Onions", "", 'Eggplant', "Cabbages"]

df.plot(kind="barh", x=x_ax, y=["Food 1", "Food 2", "Food 3", "Food 4"], stacked=True, ax=axes[1])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `''` with `np.nan` because empty stings will be counted as values.
2. Use `pandas.DataFrame.melt` to convert the dataframe to a long form.
3. Use `pandas.crosstab` with the `normalize` parameter to calculate the percent for each `'Food'`.
4. Plot the dataframe with `pandas.DataFrame.plot` and `kind='barh'`.

   - Putting the food names on the x-axis is not the correct way to create a 100% stacked bar plot. One axis must be numeric. The bars will be colored by food type.
5. Annotate the bars based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64202669/7758804).
6. Move the legend outside the plot based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700614/7758804).

- `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`, and `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the default backend, and it's easier to produce a stacked bar plot with `pandas`.

  - `seaborn` doesn't support stacked barplots, unless `histplot` is used in a hacked way, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64202669/7758804), and would require an extra step of melting `percent`.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`**

  - Assignment expressions (`:=`) require `python >= 3.8`. Otherwise, use `[f'{v.get_width():.2f}%' if v.get_width() > 0 else '' for v in c ]`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# using the dataframe in the OP

# 1.
df = df.replace('', np.nan)

# 2.
dfm = df.melt(id_vars='User', var_name='Food', value_name='Type')

# 3.
percent = pd.crosstab(dfm.Food, dfm.Type, normalize='index').mul(100).round(2)

# 4.
ax = percent.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(8, 6))

# 5.
for c in ax.containers:
    
    # customize the label to account for cases when there might not be a bar section
    labels = [f'{w:.2f}%' if (w := v.get_width()) > 0 else '' for v in c ]
    
    # set the bar label
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center')

# 6.
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

### DataFrame Views

#### `dfm`

```
     User    Food      Type
0   Steph  Food 1    Onions
1     Tom  Food 1  Potatoes
2    Fred  Food 1   Carrots
3    Phil  Food 1    Onions
4   Steph  Food 2  Tomatoes
5     Tom  Food 2  Tomatoes
6    Fred  Food 2  Cabbages
7    Phil  Food 2  Eggplant
8   Steph  Food 3  Cabbages
9     Tom  Food 3  Potatoes
10   Fred  Food 3       NaN
11   Phil  Food 3  Eggplant
12  Steph  Food 4  Potatoes
13    Tom  Food 4  Potatoes
14   Fred  Food 4  Eggplant
15   Phil  Food 4       NaN
```

#### `percent`

```
Type    Cabbages  Carrots  Eggplant  Onions  Potatoes  Tomatoes
Food                                                           
Food 1      0.00     25.0      0.00    50.0     25.00       0.0
Food 2     25.00      0.0     25.00     0.0      0.00      50.0
Food 3     33.33      0.0     33.33     0.0     33.33       0.0
Food 4      0.00      0.0     33.33     0.0     66.67       0.0
```

Comment: brilliant answer, thanks.  the if (w := v.get_width()) > 0 else '' part of the comprehension list is particularly useful as it means I can easily suppress labels for segments too small to display them by setting it to > 10 instead of 0.

Comment: @Steve you're welcome. glad this works for you