# How to create a proportional horizontal stacked bar chart with percentages

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I have been struggling to create a horizontal bar chart using python, pandas, and matplotlib.

Ideally I'd like to have percentages on the chart as well.

I merged 2 datasets together to get this:

```py
# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Moving Violation': [103281, 75376, 66957, 73071, 244090],
                   'Other Violations': [54165, 75619, 48567, 33587, 127639]},
                  index=['asian/pacific islander', 'black', 'hispanic', 'other', 'white'])

                        Moving Violation  Other Violations
asian/pacific islander            103281             54165
black                              75376             75619
hispanic                           66957             48567
other                              73071             33587
white                             244090            127639
```

I am now looking to create a stacked bar chart that looks something like this:

[image: Bar chart I want it to look like]

I am struggling to figure this out. I have used `plt.barh()`, but it has deemed to not work very well.

Comment: You ask for _**Ideally I'd like to have percentages on the chart as well.**_, yet the answer you accepted doesn't do that.

Comment: The answer that helped me had percentages on the chart.

Comment: The one with percentages on the chart is not the one you marked as the accepted answer. That's the check mark in the upper left hand corner of the answer, by the up and down arrows (for voting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through temporary df with percentage proportions of your data as in the example below. Dataframe I created has different data, but is the same type as yours.

```py
# df similar to what you have
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["a", "b", "c"], data={"aa": [1,2,3], "bb": [5,6,7]})

# percentages
df_perc = df.iloc[:, :].apply(lambda x: x / x.sum(), axis=1) * 100

# plot
df_perc.plot(ax=ax, kind="barh", stacked=True)
```

[Output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAPt9.png)

Answer (score 4):

- [How to create a 100% stacked barplot from a categorical dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72856017/7758804) is very similar, but it requires additional steps, due to the structure of the DataFrame, which aren't required for this DataFrame.
- The easiest way to plot horizontal stacked bars is to plot the DataFrame directly, using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with `kind='barh'`, and `stacked=True`.
- Calculate `percent`

  - Use [`.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) with the correct `axis=`, to create `totals` for each row.
  - Divide `df` by `totals` using [`.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with the correct `axis=`. [`.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) by 100, and [`.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) to 2 decimals places, to clean up the presentation.
  - We do not use `.apply` because it's not a fast vectorized operation.
  - `df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100).round(2)` for a single line.
- Use [`.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) to annotate the stacked bars.

  - See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for a thorough explanation and more examples with this method, which is available with `matplotlib >= v3.4.0`.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`**

```py
import pandas as pd

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Moving Violation': [103281, 75376, 66957, 73071, 244090],
                   'Other Violations': [54165, 75619, 48567, 33587, 127639]},
                  index=['asian/pacific islander', 'black', 'hispanic', 'other', 'white'])

# get the totals for each row
totals = df.sum(axis=1)

# calculate the percent for each row
percent = df.div(totals, axis=0).mul(100).round(2)

# create the plot
ax = percent.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(9, 5), color=['green', 'gray'], xticks=[])
# move the legend
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05), ncol=2, frameon=False)

# remove ticks
ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)
# remove all spines
ax.spines[['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']].set_visible(False)

# iterate through each container
for c in ax.containers:
    
    # custom label calculates percent and add an empty string so 0 value bars don't have a number
    labels = [f'{w:0.2f}%' if (w := v.get_width()) > 0 else '' for v in c]
    
    # add annotations
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center', padding=0.3, color='w')
```

[image]

### DataFrame Views

#### `df`

```
                        Moving Violation  Other Violations
asian/pacific islander            103281             54165
black                              75376             75619
hispanic                           66957             48567
other                              73071             33587
white                             244090            127639
```

#### `totals`

```
asian/pacific islander    157446
black                     150995
hispanic                  115524
other                     106658
white                     371729
dtype: int64
```

#### `percent`

```
                        Moving Violation  Other Violations
asian/pacific islander             65.60             34.40
black                              49.92             50.08
hispanic                           57.96             42.04
other                              68.51             31.49
white                              65.66             34.34
```