# what is the name of this graph and how to plot it?

Tags: python, pandas

Let say i have these two list.

```
p=[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5]
q=[1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0]
```

I want to plot it like in this picture with the color represent the number in the list like green is 0 or yellow is 1. Above lists are not the real data for the graph in the picture below. The picture is just example of the graph i want to create.  [image]

Comment: This is a horizontal stacked bar chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given graph can be created using `pandas` as a horizontal stacked bar chart. You will need to convert your dataset to a dataframe before that though.

```
from itertools import groupby
data=[(key,len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(p)]
print(data)

list1, list2 = zip(*data)

df2=pd.DataFrame([list2],columns=list1)
df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654500/6224662)

You can plot the same using matplotlib to customize the orientation, xticks, yticks, label methods, width and more to look like your requirement.

Comment: I tried your code but its slightly different from what i want. I need same color for a number like if there 4 between 3 like in list p, the second 3 still use same color like the first 3. If you notice in the pic, there are three times the green color comes up in first graph.

Comment: You need to change how your data frame looks for something like this and associate colours according to that. This code is plotting the overall frequency in the array and not continuous frequency.

Comment: can you tell me how should I change my data frame?

Comment: I got it.  My friend added these to your code and got the graph. Thank you for helping.
color=["r", "g", "b", "k", "c", "m", "y"]
colorlist = [color[i] for i in list1]